Aligning part of the line to the right with pandoc (md -> html)
I'm using pandoc to render markdown into html. Markdown does not really support aligning text to the right, so I'm looking for some trick to align a part of a line to the right.
left text right text

the final rendered html should be like so
left text                                right text

I've tried inline html and latex macros, both did not work. I'm open for any solution. I was thinking even about using a special character sequence like -> that gets converted inline via sed before sending it to pandoc.

use pandoc's native spans and add some CSS?

can you give an example how that would look like?

One way would be to leverage the fenced span syntax that's supported by pandoc's Markdown flavor:
left text [right text]{style="float:right"}

This will give the right result for HTML. For PDF output via LaTeX, it's enough to insert some raw LaTeX snippet:
left text \hfill right text

Both methods can be combined, which gives
left text \hfill [right text]{style="float:right"}

